# Opening a specific worksheet in a specific workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Dim conRow As Long
Dim targetBook As Workbooks
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetRng As Range


targetBook = Workbooks("C:\file\path\here\filename.xlsx")
targetSheet = Worksheets("SheetName")
targetRng = Range("$A:$A")

conRow = Application.Match("APersonsName", Workbooks(targetBook).Sheets(targetSheet).targetRng, 0)
```

This code gives invalid use of property at the line where targetBook is assigned. Basically I am trying to look up a persons name in a given range in a given worksheet in a given workbook; to be later used for looking up various attributes associated with that row.

Maybe I am using the wrong functions? I was under the impression that the function I use could take both indexes and strings as arguments.

Comment: In addition as you set each you will be setting the parent at that time. so `Set targetSheet = targetBook.Worksheets("SheetName")` and `Set targetRng = targetSheet.Range("$A:$A")` and then in your formula you only refer to the rang and not the parents as the parents are already assigned to the range variable. `conRow = Application.Match("APersonsName", targetRng, 0)`

Comment: @ScottCraner - thanks for pointing out my deliberate mistake! I've deleted my answer as don't think it adds anything to your comment.

Comment: @SJR there is nothing wrong with taking a comment and turning it into a complete answer.  No one should get upset with that.  If you want to take my comment and provide a complete answer, feel free.

Comment: @ScottCraner - that's generous of you, but it's fine. The only other thing I spotted is that the correct declaration would be `As Workbook` rather than `Workbooks`.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I am trying to set the workbook object: Set targetBook = Workbooks("C:\file\path\here\filename.xlsx") and it is giving me a "subscript out of range" error. Where would I look for regarding the reason as to this error? Thanks again.

Comment: Is the workbook already opened? If it is not you'll have to use `Workbooks.Open("C:\file\path\here\filename.xlsx")` to actually open the workbook.

Comment: Do i need to open the workbook? I cant reference the workbook without opening it?

Comment: It's not impossible to do without opening the workbook, but if you turn off screenupdating you can open and close a workbook without noticing. Then you'd use `Set targetBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\file\path\here\filename.xlsx")`

Comment: @SJR - **not impossible** or **impossible** or **not possible**?

Comment: @Jeeped - the first. I think ADO is an option. I used it once many moons ago but don't know enough to know if it would meet the OP's needs.

Comment: @SJR - that's a good point but semantics aside, isn't opening an ADO connection a form of 'opening' the workbook?

Comment: @Jeeped - it seems to be generally regarded as an alternative to opening a workbook, but you may well be right that the distinction is a slim one. In this particular case, as the OP is just using a match formula could one not "write the formula to the worksheet, collect the returned value and then clear the formula" as you wrote below?

Comment: @SJR - Yes but that is non-elegant (aka ugly) code and not something I would proselytize. I included it only as an example of what must be done.

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>Do i need to open the workbook? I cant reference the workbook without opening it?</sub>

**tldr:**
**No**. You cannot reference an unopened workbook in VBA; not even with `Application.Evaluate` of a formula that works on the worksheet. You would need to write the formula to the worksheet, collect the returned value and then clear the formula.

**more ...**
You cannot `Set` a var to a closed workbook object. You need to set the var to an open workbook or to the `Workbooks.Open` command as you open it. Since you cannot set a var to the unopened workbook, it follows that you cannot use that workbook object reference to set a worksheet or worksheet range/cells object either.

```
Dim strPath As String, strSheet As String, strLookup As String, var As Variant

Dim targetBook As Workbook   '<~~ note Workbook object, not Workbooks collection
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet, targetRng As Range

strPath = "C:\file\path\here\filename.xlsx"
strSheet = "SheetName"
strLookup = "aPersonsName"

Set targetBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath, readonly:=true)
Set targetSheet = targetBook.Worksheets(strSheet)
Set targetRng = targetSheet.Range("A:A")

var = Application.Match(strLookup, targetRng, 0)

If Not IsError(var) Then
    Debug.Print var
End If

targetBook.Close savechanges:=False
```

You have already qualified `targetRng`'s parent worksheet and workbook when you set it. You do not need to repeat the qualification in the match.